# understanding use of translateZ for 3d accelaration

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i was just going through the source of odoeter.js and came across the following line of code ::

```
        <!-- Force 3d acceleration always and forever :) -->
        <div style="-webkit-transform: translateZ(0)"></div>
```

what is this for ? i don't quite understand .

I am refering to this page of **[odometer.js](http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/docs/welcome/)** .

can somebody explain this with a simple example ?

Thank you.

Alexander.

Comment: It's for 3d accelaration! Some browsers activate the graphics card for rendering when you use 3d css transforms. (Even if they have the value 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using translateZ (or another 3d animation) you are enabling hardware acceleration for your animations, even if it's a fake 3d animation like `0`, as it doesn't do anything but enabling HA. HA will improve the animations smoothness. If you are planing to use javascript for animations, I'd have a look at velocity.js which outscores jQuery's animate() by far. Have a look [here](http://julian.com/research/velocity/) for comparisons.

To further improve the animations speed, make sure to add

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
backface-visibility: hidden;
perspective: 1000;
```

To your animated elements.

Comment: can you attach external links to support your point of `backface-visibility` , `perspective` .

Comment: Just google for 'translateZ hardware acceleration'. At least the first five hits suggest this